# How to build an HTML template for Java Mail

Tags: java

I am using java mail to send html content for creating html content.

Here is what I've got:

```
String format = "
<div style=\"font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #eee;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;\">"
     + "    
<div style=\"width:46em; 
background: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left; \">"
```

I would also like to use bootstreap or any another library want to include css file insted of inline css.

How could I reduce my code to avoid use of inline CSS?

Comment: Some tools @ [*Java HTML Generator v0.9*](http://artho.com/webtools/java/HtmlExample.html), [*DOM4J*](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).

And you can do something like this:

yourfile.html

```
<h1 style="color: #00">$entity.header</h1>
```

MyOwnEntity.java

```
public class MyOwnEntity{
private String header;

public MyOwnEntity(String header){
    this.header = header;
}

public getHeader(){
    return header;
}}
```

TemplateLoader.java

```
public class TemplateLoader {

public static <ENTITY> String loadFilledTemplate(ENTITY entity, String templatePath) throws IOException {
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    Velocity.init(p);

    final VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("entity", entity);
    final Template template = Velocity.getTemplate(templatePath);
    try (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
        template.merge(context, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}}
```

In your class

```
 String format = TemplateLoader.loadFilledTemplate(new MyOwnEntity("custom"), "yourfile.html");
```